# How to use key values as another plotting point

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, associations

I have this list:

```
    testdata= <|"A" -> "20190727_161848", 
 "X" -> {777.708, 777.824, 777.94, 778.057, 778.173, 778.289, 
   778.406, 778.522, 778.638, 778.754, 778.87, 778.986, 779.103, 
   779.219, 779.335, 779.451}, 
 "Y" -> {0.539375, 0.545771, 0.545604, 0.542646, 0.544688, 
   0.538229, 0.539021, 0.536, 0.546875, 0.536938, 0.538167, 0.542583, 
   0.556417, 0.556104, 0.544896, 0.533396}, 
 "Z" -> 0.0334273|>
```

I would like to plot lines and use the value of `Z` as a color legend. Here's what I have tried so far after trying many times:

```
    ListLogPlot[<|#A -> Transpose@{#X, #Y}, 
    PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][#Z]|> & /@ 
  testdata, Joined -> True]
```

However, nothing shows up. Could someone let me know what I am doing wrong here?
I had an idea of associating the values with `Z` instead of `A` but I had so many lists it was impossible.

Comment: Use an anonymous function and named slots with associations: see the examples in [`Slot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) documentation. Then your example will be `ListLogPlot[<|#A -> Transpose@{#X, #Y}|>, PlotStyle  ->  ColorData["Rainbow"][#Z], Joined  ->  True]& [testdata]`.

Comment: @creidhne, thank you for your help! I get an error message `(ListLogPlot[<|#A -> Transpose@{#X, #Y}|>, PlotStyle  ->  ColorData["Rainbow"][#Z], Joined  ->  True]& [testdata] is expected to have an Association as the first argument)`but I am certain that it does have an association which is `A`?

Comment: @creidhne Sorry should've clarified that I modified it to `ListLogPlot[<|#A -> Transpose@{#X, #Y}|>, 
   PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][#Z], 
   Joined -> True] & /@ testdata` and I get multiple individual plots with no color legends `Z`? Is it possible to join them all in one plot?

Comment: Yes, well, as you've seen, your modification will not work. You must use an anonymous function to use the named slots that are defined in `testdata`.

Comment: @creidhne Oh got it, thanks for your help. I will go over the doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume we have a number of associations that are arranged like `testdata`, and each one has values for `A`, `X`, `Y` and `Z`. We want `Z` to control the color of the plotted data. We make a list of associations (two associations in this example, but there could be more). Then we can plot the values from `testdatalist`.

```
testdatalist = {
 <|"A" -> "20190727_161848",
 "X" -> {777.708, 777.824, 777.94, 778.057, 778.173, 778.289, 
   778.406, 778.522, 778.638, 778.754, 778.87, 778.986, 779.103, 
   779.219, 779.335, 779.451}, 
 "Y" -> {0.539375, 0.545771, 0.545604, 0.542646, 0.544688, 
   0.538229, 0.539021, 0.536, 0.546875, 0.536938, 0.538167, 0.542583, 
   0.556417, 0.556104, 0.544896, 0.533396}, 
 "Z" -> 0.0334273|>,
 <|"A" -> "20190727_161849",
 "X" -> {777.708, 777.824, 777.94, 778.057, 778.173, 778.289, 
   778.406, 778.522, 778.638, 778.754, 778.87, 778.986, 779.103, 
   779.219, 779.335, 779.451}, 
 "Y" -> {0.532636,0.549407,0.547867,0.54763,0.552863,0.5492,0.544157,
 0.548192,0.543975,0.555481,0.551747,0.543945,
 0.545864,0.553219,0.538701,0.541},
 "Z" -> 0.8|>};

ListLogPlot[<|#A -> Transpose@{#X, #Y}|>,
  PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][#Z], Joined -> True]&[#] &/@ testdatalist
```

[image: example plots for a list of associations]

---

### Update for comment: Combine all plots together and add a key legend that shows the value of Z.

Combine data for each of the `X` and `Y` data sets from `testdatalist`. Create legends and styles for the matching data sets.

```
data = Transpose[{#X, #Y}]&[#] &/@ testdatalist;
legends = # &/@ testdatalist[[All, "Z"]];
styles = ColorData["Rainbow", #] &/@ testdatalist[[All, "Z"]];

ListLogPlot[data, PlotLegends -> legends, PlotStyle -> styles, Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot for combined data]

Comment: Thank you. I did get the same outcome from your previous comment. Is there a way to combine all plots together and add a key legend that shows the value of Z?

Answer (score 3):

Using:

```
testdatalist = {<|"A" -> "20190727_161848", 
    "X" -> {777.708, 777.824, 777.94, 778.057, 778.173, 778.289, 
      778.406, 778.522, 778.638, 778.754, 778.87, 778.986, 779.103, 
      779.219, 779.335, 779.451}, 
    "Y" -> {0.539375, 0.545771, 0.545604, 0.542646, 0.544688, 
      0.538229, 0.539021, 0.536, 0.546875, 0.536938, 0.538167, 
      0.542583, 0.556417, 0.556104, 0.544896, 0.533396}, 
    "Z" -> 0.0334273|>, <|"A" -> "20190727_161849", 
    "X" -> {777.708, 777.824, 777.94, 778.057, 778.173, 778.289, 
      778.406, 778.522, 778.638, 778.754, 778.87, 778.986, 779.103, 
      779.219, 779.335, 779.451}, 
    "Y" -> {0.532636, 0.549407, 0.547867, 0.54763, 0.552863, 0.5492, 
      0.544157, 0.548192, 0.543975, 0.555481, 0.551747, 0.543945, 
      0.545864, 0.553219, 0.538701, 0.541}, "Z" -> 0.8|>};
```

You can use:

```
trs = {#1, #2, 
     Thread[#3]} & @@@ ({"A", 
        ColorData["Rainbow"]["Z"], {"X", "Y"}} /. # & /@ testdatalist);
ListLogPlot[trs[[All, 3]], PlotStyle -> trs[[All, 2]], Joined -> True,
  PlotLegends -> trs[[All, 1]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The X- and Y-values have different lengths. Therefore, I
dropped the last 3 values of `testdata["X"]`. You might want
to drop other values. In any case, `X` and `Y` must have the same lengths, otherwise you cannot cannot `Transpose` them.

```
tdat = Transpose[{testdata["X"][[;; -4]], testdata["Y"]}];

ListLogPlot[tdat, 
 Joined -> True,
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry just fixed the mismatched lengths of data. I want to use `Z` values as color legends for each line though. Is that possible?